# How to get tab autocompletion in bash to replace an expanded $(command)?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a small bash script `get_path` that takes in an argument and returns a predetermined path to stdout. For example, I can use it to copy a file to a "project1" directory in the following way:

```
$ cp file1 $(get_path project1)
```

In above example `$(get_path project1)` expands to something like `/path/to/project1/`. To copy the file to `/path/to/project1/dir1/` I want to be able to use autocompletion and do something like:

```
$ cp file1 $(get_path project1)/d<tab_key>
```

When I try this, bash autocompletes it to:

```
$ cp file1 $(get_path /path/to/project1/dir1/
```

i.e., the `$(get_path` part is not replaced. How do I fix this?

Comment: I can't even reproduce the autocompletion you describe. Have you set any special shell options to that effect?

Comment: Modify your get_path script to just return the full path `$1` if `$1` start with a '/'. Something like `if [ "${1:0:1}" = "/" ] ; then echo "$1"; return 0; fi`.

Comment: Commands inside `$( )` are executed when you press enter, not while you type.  I will keep watch here, but as far as I know, it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shell-expand-line` `readline` command for this, usually bound to <kbd>Esc,Ctrl-e</kbd>:

```
$ bind -P | grep shell-expand-line
shell-expand-line can be found on "\e\C-e".
```

For example, type `echo "$(echo foo)"`, press and release <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-e</kbd>, and the command is replaced with `echo foo`.